# What state am I modifying during view update?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a CoreData object `Day` which I am editing within this view, when in "editing" mode the card allows for a `Picker` view and then a `TextField` to allow user input. These all work as expected, however when I tap "done" which runs the `saveEditToDay()` function which is just saving those into the `Day` variable. This crashes with `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1cffc77e0)` and gives the hint `Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.`. I am not clear what state I modifying in this case?

Here is the view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct EditCard: View {

    @Binding var day: Day?
    var timeOfDay: Time
    @State var isEditing: Bool = false
    @State var selectedRating = 0
    @State var description = ""
    var ratings = Rating.getAllRatings()

    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text(timeOfDay.rawValue).font(.headline)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    if self.isEditing { self.saveEditToDay() }
                    self.isEditing.toggle()
                }, label: { self.isEditing ? Text("Done") : Text("Edit") })
                    .foregroundColor(Color("PrimaryColour"))
            }

            Divider()

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("RATING")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))

                if isEditing {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedRating, label: Text("")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< ratings.count) {
                            Text(self.ratings[$0]).tag([$0])
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Text(day!.getRating(for: timeOfDay))
                }

            }.padding(.trailing)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("REASON")
                   .font(.caption)
                   .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))

                if isEditing {
                    TextField(description, text: $description)
                } else {
                    Text(description)
                       .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                       .lineLimit(nil)
                }

           }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground))
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .onAppear { self.setSelected() }
        .onDisappear{ self.saveEditToDay(); print("Toodles") }
    }

    // MARK: - Functions
    func setSelected() {
        guard let day = day else { return }
        self.selectedRating = ratings.firstIndex(of: day.getRating(for: timeOfDay))!
        self.description = day.getDescription(for: timeOfDay)
    }

    func saveEditToDay() {
        guard let day = day else { return }
        day.setRating(rating: ratings[selectedRating], for: timeOfDay)
        day.setDescription(description: description, for: timeOfDay)
    }
}
```

Here at the Extensions to the NSManagedObject that i'm calling:

```swift
func setRating(rating: String, for time: Time) {
     switch time {
     case .morning: self.morning = rating;
     case .afternoon: self.afternoon = rating;
     case .evening: self.evening = rating;
     }
}

func setDescription(description: String, for time: Time) {
     switch time {
     case .morning: self.morningDescription = description;
     case .afternoon: self.afternoonDescription = description;
     case .evening: self.eveningDescription = description;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `setSelected()` in `onApear()`, which modifies two of your variables marked as `@State`: `selectedRating` and `description`. This means that as the view gets drawn or redrawn you are changing the variables that define what is being drawn halfway through the process.
`onApear()` is a good place to trigger a background refresh, but not modify any `@State` variables instantly.
You probably should write an initialiser that takes binding to a `Day` and `Time` sets the other two variables just like you do in `setSelected()`.

Comment: [This article](https://swiftui-lab.com/state-changes/) states that `onAppear()` is a **safe** place to change `@State` variables.  Any insight into why the difference?